# SQL Server: How to display a specific character based on position in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, position, substring

So I'm attempting to display a single character based on its position in a string from one column. Since this is grid data, there is a simple math to it. The grid has 24 rows 'A-X', and 44 columns.

So lets say I want to see the value in D9. I already know the expected value should be a 'A1', so that means the character length is '2'. If I do the math: (A + B + C = 3 x 44, + 9). That two-character value for D9 starts at the 141st position of that string in Col2. I attempted to use SUBSTRING with no success

```
SELECT 
Col1 , SUBSTRING('Col2',141,2)
FROM Table1
```

Query result displays data in Col1, but for Col2 its just blank. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Asked too soon. Figured out I had to remove the **'** from the column name

```
SELECT 
Col1 , SUBSTRING('Col2',141,2)
FROM Table1
```

Didn't work

```
SELECT 
Col1 , SUBSTRING(Col2,141,2)
FROM Table1
```

Works

Comment: Great you figured it out yourself. Please accept your answer so the question could be closed. Cheers!!

Comment: Actually I don't think he can for another 2 days. @Utsav

Comment: Oh. Didn't know that. Thanks.